# Xamarin.Forms - Release apk not installing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to install the application as a release APK in my android device but it is crashing when the installation of the application starts. When I run the app on release mode directly from the visual studio, it is showing no error and worked perfectly.

When the same signed APK file I am trying to install in the same or some other android device it just crashed when the installation of the application starts.

The linking property of the Android project is set to None (tried with all the three options), the minimum Android version is jelly bean and maximum version is Oreo 8.1.

I am using the latest Xamarin.Forms package and visual studio 2017. My Android SDK is updated. Please let me know what corrections do I need to make in order to successfully run the APK on all the devices.

Comment: Did you sign the apk? Go through the [release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows) and [sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/index?tabs=windows) docs

Comment: Have you [`zipaligned`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign) the apk?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no success

Comment: What is reported in `logcat`?

Comment: @SushiHangover I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @SushiHangover, It is working fine in both release and debug mode, when running directly from VS but causing issue when we install apk in any of device.

Comment: Review the `logcat` output to determine why the app is crashing and/or the installation is failing. Without that information, anything else is just a guess: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am checking it

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover, I am able to resolve my issue, the app logo using in my project was quite large. I have resized it now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are possible things which can help you

1. Remove the old build from mobile and restart the mobile. while releasing, delete bin and obj folders, clean the solution and rebuild the solution after rebuilding deploy the solution
2. In android manifest file Set target android version to (api 27) oreo instead **Use Compile using SDK.**
3. Check the permission in release mode like (Internet, wifi and other permission which your app needs).